# Calling a javascript function that contains dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a javascript function that contains dynamic variable as a parameter. I think i am failing in the syntax to get this particular function executed. I have tried a few combinations and none of them seem to work. Please can someone advise..

```
 for( i=0; i<succeedList.length; i++){
     var file_uniq_id = succeedList[i].filename_uniq;

 //Creating dynamic button
 var subm_btn = document.createElement("INPUT");
 subm_btn.setAttribute("onclick", "UploadMyScript.submitTitle(this.id,'+file_uniq_id+')");
 p_titleBtn.appendChild(subm_btn);
}



 UploadMyScript.submitTitle = function(id, uniqID){
 // Does something ....
 }
```

My problem is I cannot appear to pass on the 'file_uniq_id' value to UploadMyScript.submitTitle().

Comment: `subm_btn.setAttribute("onclick", "UploadMyScript.submitTitle(this.id,'+file_uniq_id+')"); ` contains a string as the second parameter. You probably want `subm_btn.setAttribute("onclick", UploadMyScript.submitTitle(this.id,'+file_uniq_id+')); `

Comment: because you are not concatenating correctly because you used the wrong quote to end the string, it should be: `"+file_uniq_id+"`

Comment: What does `I cannot appear to pass on the 'file_uniq_id' value to UploadMyScript.submitTitle().` mean? What happens when you try? Do you get an error? What is the error? What line causes it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use an event listener ?

```
subm_btn.addEventListener('click', function () { 
    UploadMyScript.submitTitle(subm_btn.id, file_uniq_id); },
false);
```

Comment: When i use this event listener. The error that i am getting back is 'Uncaught ReferenceError: file_unique_id is not defined'.

Comment: i am sorry i do not understand. I pretty much cut and paste your code for the event listener instead of the code i used to listen for the onclick event therefore i do pass on the file_uniq_id variable.

Comment: Check the edit. I initially wrote `file_unique_id`, but the correct one is `file_uniq_id` - Notice the lack of **ue** in the variable name? I would suggest to read on event listeners.